# Converting a list of dictionaries, into rdf format

Tags: python, rdf

Goal:(Automation: When there is large list of dictionaries, i want to generate a spectic format  of data)
this is the input:

```
a = ['et2': 'OBJ Type',
  'e2': 'OBJ',
  'rel': 'rel',
  'et1': 'SUJ Type',
  'e1': 'SUJ'},
     {'et2': 'OBJ Type 2',
  'e2': 'OBJ',
  'rel': 'rel',
  'et1': 'SUJ Type',
  'e1': 'SUJ'}
  ]
```

The expected output is this :

```
:Sub a :SubType.
:Sub :rel "Obj".
```

This is what i have tried

```
Sub = 0


for i in a:
    entity_type1 = i["EntityType1"]
    entity1 = i["Entity1"]
    entity_type2 = i["EntityType2"]
    entity2 = i["Entity2"]
    relation = i["Relation"]
    if 'Sub' in entity_type1 or entity_type2:
        if entity1 == Sub and Sub <= 0 :
            
            Sub +=1
            sd_line1 = ""
            sd_line2 = ""
            sd_line1 = ":" + entity1 + " a " + ":" + entity_type1 + "."
            relation = ":"+relation
            sd_line2 ="\n"  ":" + entity1 + " " + relation + " \"" + entity2 + "\"."
            sd_line3 = sd_line1 + sd_line2
            print(sd_line3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of advice: when doing such a transformation workflow, try to separate the major steps, e.g.: *loading* from a system, *parsing* data in one format, *extracting*, *transforming*, *serializing* to another format, *loading* to another system.

In your code example, you are mixing the extraction, transformation and serialization steps. Separating those steps will make your code easier to read and, thus, easier to maintain or reuse.

Below, I give you two solutions: the first is extracting data to a simple `dict`-based `subject-predicate-object` graph, the second one to a real RDF graph.

In both cases, you'll see that I separated the extraction/transformation steps (that returns a graph) and serialization steps (that uses the graph), making them more reusable:

- the `dict`-based transformation is implemented with a simple `dict` or with a `defaultdict`. The serialization step is common to both.
- the `rdflib.Graph`-based transformation is common to two serializations: one to your format, the other one to any available `rdflib.Graph` serializations.

---

This will build a simple `dict`-based graph from your `a` dictionary:

```py
graph = {}

for e in a:
    subj = e["Entity1"]
    graph[subj] = {}

    # :Entity1 a :EntityType1.
    obj = e["EntityType1"]
    graph[subj]["a"] = obj  

    # :Entity1 :Relation "Entity2".    
    pred, obj = e["Relation"], e["Entity2"]
    graph[subj][pred] = obj  

print(graph)
```

like this:

```py
{'X450-G2': {'a': 'switch',
             'hasFeatures': 'Role-Based Policy',
             'hasLocation': 'WallJack'},
 'ers 3600': {'a': 'switch', 
              'hasFeatures': 'ExtremeXOS'},
 'slx 9540': {'a': 'router',
              'hasFeatures': 'ExtremeXOS',
              'hasLocation': 'Chasis'}})
```

Or, in a shorter form, with a `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

graph = defaultdict(dict)

for e in a:
    subj = e["Entity1"]
    
    # :Entity1 a :EntityType1.
    graph[subj]["a"] = e["EntityType1"]  

    # :Entity1 :Relation "Entity2".    
    graph[subj][e["Relation"]] = e["Entity2"]  

print(graph)
```

And this will print your `subject predicate object.` triples from the graph:

```py
def normalize(text):
    return text.replace(' ', '')

for subj, po in graph.items():
    subj = normalize(subj)

    # :Entity1 a :EntityType1.
    print(':{} a :{}.'.format(subj, po.pop("a")))

    for pred, obj in po.items():
        # :Entity1 :Relation "Entity2".    
        print(':{} :{} "{}".'.format(subj, pred, obj))

    print()
```

like this:

```
:X450-G2 a :switch.
:X450-G2 :hasFeatures "Role-Based Policy".
:X450-G2 :hasLocation "WallJack".

:ers3600 a :switch.
:ers3600 :hasFeatures "ExtremeXOS".

:slx9540 a :router.
:slx9540 :hasFeatures "ExtremeXOS".
:slx9540 :hasLocation "Chasis".
```

---

This will build a real RDF graph using the `rdflib` library:

```py
from rdflib import Graph, Literal, URIRef
from rdflib.namespace import RDF

A = RDF.type
graph = Graph()

for d in a:
   subj = URIRef(normalize(d["Entity1"]))

    # :Entity1 a :EntityType1.
    graph.add((
        subj,
        A, 
        URIRef(normalize(d["EntityType1"]))
    ))
    
    # :Entity1 :Relation "Entity2".    
    graph.add((
        subj,
        URIRef(normalize(d["Relation"])), 
        Literal(d["Entity2"])
    ))
```

This:

```py
print(graph.serialize(format="n3").decode("utf-8"))
```

will print the graph in the `N3` serialization format:

```
<X450-G2> a <switch> ;
    <hasFeatures> "Role-Based Policy" ;
    <hasLocation> "WallJack" .

<ers3600> a <switch> ;
    <hasFeatures> "ExtremeXOS" .

<slx9540> a <router> ;
    <hasFeatures> "ExtremeXOS" ;
    <hasLocation> "Chasis" .
```

And this will query the graph to print it in your format:

```py
for subj in set(graph.subjects()):
    po = dict(graph.predicate_objects(subj))
    
    # :Entity1 a :EntityType1.
    print(":{} a :{}.".format(subj, po.pop(A)))
    
    for pred, obj in po.items():
        # :Entity1 :Relation "Entity2".    
        print(':{} :{} "{}".'.format(subj, pred, obj))
    print()
```

Comment: Okay , python is really cool, thank you  so much  for the information George:)

Comment: Martin : while i am trying to write the print statememt in a file this line is throwing a key error.
    print(':{} a :{}.'.format(subj, po.pop("a")))<-- this line
    f.write(':{} a :{}.'.format(subj, po.pop("a")))

Comment: '    :X450-G2 a :switch.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-ece0a9cdcf39> in <module>
     26 
     27     print(':{} a :{}.'.format(subj, po.pop("a")))
---> 28     f.write(':%s a :%s'%(subj, po.pop("a")))
     29 
     30     for pred, obj in po.items():

KeyError: 'a'
`

Comment: `po.pop("a")` will *remove* the key "a" from the po dictionary, and return its value. If you call it twice, the second call will not find that key in the dictionary anymore, hence the ˋKeyError` exception. I suggest you put a ˋa = po.pop("a")ˋ line before the ˋprint` and ˋf.write`lines and replace the ˋpo.pop("a")ˋ in those lines with... ˋa`.

Comment: that is working fine , thank you learnt a lot with this exercise , thank you for the reply..